# Disable "Default export is not declared in imported module" warning of WebStorm 2017.1

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, webstorm

I'm working with VueJS and I like to keep my code clean, so sometimes my components only have the `<template>` section without the `<script>` where an object should be exported. Therefore I want to switch this warning off but I'm not able to it.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "my components only have the section without the where an object should be exported" ?

Comment: Hi @loganfsmyth, it seems that when I posted my question, the tags didn't appear properly, but thanks to LazyOne I think now make sense. If not please let me know.

Comment: please feel free to file a request for disabling this warning in vue files to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB